# xmlNodeGetContent introduces newlines

Tags: c, libxml2

It seems xmlNodeGetContent introduces newlines, where there shouldn't be.

This a node dump:

```
ELEMENT td
  ATTRIBUTE width
    TEXT
      content=100%
  ATTRIBUTE bgcolor
    TEXT
      content=#FFFFFF
  ELEMENT font
    ATTRIBUTE face
      TEXT
        content=Arial,Helvetica
    ELEMENT font
      ATTRIBUTE color
        TEXT
          content=#0000FF
      ELEMENT font
        ATTRIBUTE size
          TEXT
            content=-1
        ELEMENT b
          ELEMENT br
  TEXT
    content= 
  ELEMENT hr
  ELEMENT font
    ATTRIBUTE face
      TEXT
        content=Arial,Helvetica
    ELEMENT font
      ATTRIBUTE color
        TEXT
          content=#0000FF
      ELEMENT font
        ATTRIBUTE size
          TEXT
            content=-1
        ELEMENT b
          TEXT
            content=love
        ELEMENT br
  TEXT
    content= 
  ELEMENT ul
    ELEMENT li
      ELEMENT small
        ELEMENT font
          ATTRIBUTE color
            TEXT
              content=#FF0000
          TEXT
            content=s
        TEXT
          content= iubire 
        ELEMENT font
          ATTRIBUTE color
            TEXT
              content=#FF0000
          TEXT
            content=f
        TEXT
          content=; dragoste 
        ELEMENT font
          ATTRIBUTE color
            TEXT
              content=#FF0000
          TEXT
            content=f
        TEXT
          content=; scump 
        ELEMENT font
          ATTRIBUTE color
            TEXT
              content=#FF0000
          TEXT
            content=m
        TEXT
          content=; 
        ELEMENT font
          ATTRIBUTE color
            TEXT
              content=#0000FF
          TEXT
            content=to be in love with
        TEXT
          content= a fi #C3#AEndr#C4#83gostit de; 
        ELEMENT font
          ATTRIBUTE color
            TEXT
              content=#0000FF
          TEXT
            content=to send one's love
        TEXT
          content= a transmite complimente; 
        ELEMENT font
          ATTRIBUTE color
            TEXT
              content=#0000FF
          TEXT
            content=love affair
        TEXT
          content= amor; 
        ELEMENT font
          ATTRIBUTE color
            TEXT
              content=#0000FF
          TEXT
            content=lovelorn
        TEXT
          content= dezn#C4#83d#C4#83jduit
    TEXT
      content= 
    ELEMENT li
      ELEMENT small
        ELEMENT font
          ATTRIBUTE color
            TEXT
              content=#FF0000
          TEXT
            content=vt
        TEXT
          content= a iubi; a-i pl#C4#83cea
    TEXT
      content=
```

And this is the text as returned by xmlNodeGetContent:

```
  s iubire f; dragoste f; scump
  m; to be in love
  with a fi îndrăgostit de; to send
  one's love a transmite complimente; love affair amor; lovelorn deznădăjduit
  vt a iubi; a-i
  plăcea
```

As you can see there are line breaks where there shouldn't be.

Comment: Is this a question? Could not find one question-mark .... Please add some code examples also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the unhelpful comments (really, is not obvious what the question was?), I would like to share my explanation.

The extra lines where due to HTML Tidy prettifying the document.

Comment: what did you do to get rid of the unwanted line breaks?